# Get max value of List Point with condition

Tags: c#, list, max, points

I have a list of **Points**. `List<Point> points = new List<Point>();`

I want to get the biggest value of y coordinates inside the list, given the condition that it only scans the coordinates inside the list with a specific x coordinate.

**For example:**

I have points like this

```
(1,1)
(1,2)
(1,3)
(1,4)
(1,5)
(2,1)
(2,2)
(2,3)
(2,4)
(2,5)
```

I want to find the biggest value of y-axis or y-coordinate, given that it only search coordinates with 2 as value of x. so the output must be **(2,5)**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use LINQ to get point with biggest Y coordinate:

```
Point maximumPoint = points.First(p => p.X == 2 &&
                                       p.Y == points.Max(po => po.Y));
```

OR

```
Point maximumPoint = new Point(2, points.Where(p => p.X == 2).Max(p => p.Y));
```

Answer (score 1):

With LINQ, you can do:

```
var result = points.Where(point => point.X == 2)
                   .Max(point => point.Y);
```

If you want the Point instead of just the Y-coordinate, it's simple enough to just new up a Point wih (2, result).
But in more complex cases, consider a `MaxBy` operator, such as the [one that comes with morelinq](https://code.google.com/p/morelinq/source/browse/MoreLinq/MaxBy.cs).

Answer (score 1):

With linq, this would by

```
var maxY = points.Where(p => p.X == 2).Select(p=> p.Y).Max();
```

Answer (score 1):

This perhaps:

```
var maxY = points.Where(po => po.X == 2).Max(po => po.Y);
var q = points.Where(p => 
        p.Y == maxY  && 
        p.X == 2).FirstOrDefault();
```